# Chrome on Macbook doesn't open under admin user ID

Tags: google-chrome, macos-sierra

I have a MacBook Pro running macOS Sierra v 10.12.2 and just downloaded Chrome from google. When I try to open Chrome from Applications, it appears to start with the Chrome icon appearing in the doc, but stops after a second.
I tested with a separate user non-admin account, it works fine. 
Is there any way to run Chrome on my main admin user ID?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a somewhat similar problem with Chrome opening and freezing and this is what I did to fix it. My situation, however, was slightly different. I had chrome running already on an earlier version of OS X and upgraded to Sierra. After the update I found Chrome would open but just spin with no connection and ultimately time-out. Safari worked fine. Eventually I tried going to the menu bar, Chrome, Preferences, Settings and clicking on "Show Advanced Settings". Under "system" uncheck "use hardware acceleration when available".
W